# Can AutoInvalidateCacheOutput from ASP.NET Web API CacheOutput invalidate any Memory Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, asp.net-web-api, invalidation

AutoInvalidateCacheOutput - invalidate Web API Cache Output on controller level. (resource : [Link](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache) )

Can this attribute also invalidate memory cache for some controllers where i don't use Web API Cache Output? I save data in Memory Cache manualy.